# Using the same variables in different functions in Python

Tags: python, function, return

I'm trying to use the return function, I'm new to python but it is one of the things I don't seem to understand.

In my assignment I have to put each task in a function to make it easier to read and understand but for example I create a randomly generated number in a function, I then need the same generated number in a different function and I believe the only way this can be done is by returning data.
For example here I have a function generating a random number:

```
def generate():
    import random
    key = random.randint(22, 35)
    print(key)
```

But if I need to use the variable 'key' again which holds the same random number in a different function, it won't work as it is not defined in the new function.

```
def generate():
    import random
    key = random.randint(22, 35)
    print(key)

def number():
    sum = key + 33
```

So how would I return data (if that is what you need to use) for it to work?

Comment: You mention how to do it in your question, `return`.

Comment: `return key` instead of `print(key)` and `sum = generate() + 33` instead of `sum = key + 33`

Answer (score 1):

The usage of return indicates to your method to 'return' something back to whatever called it. So, what you want to do for example in your method is simply add a return(key):

```
# Keep your imports at the top of your script. Don't put them inside methods.
import random

def generate():
    key = random.randint(22, 35)
    print(key)
    # return here
    return key
```

When you call generate, do this:

`result_of_generate = generate()`

If you are looking to use it in your number method, you can actually simply do this:

```
def number():
    key = generate() 
    sum = key + 33
```

And if you have to return the sum then, again, make use of that return in the method in similar nature to the generate method.